# update doctrine with join table

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I am trying to update the field "note" in Note Entity which have a relation ManyToOne (bidirectionnel) with "ElementModule" and "Inscription", the entity "Inscription" have a relation ManyToOne with the  "Etudiant" Entity

I tried this DQL Query:

```
$query = $this->_em->createQuery('update UaePortailBundle:Note u JOIN u.inscription i JOIN u.elementmodule e join i.etudiant et set u.note = ?3
                                                where et.id = ?1 and e.id = ?2 ');
    $query->setParameter(1, $etudiant);
    $query->setParameter(2, $element);
    $query->setParameter(3, $note);
    $resultat = $query->execute();
```

i get this error

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 50: Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_EQUALS, got 'i'
```

Answer (score 2):

LEFT JOIN, or JOINs in particular are only supported in UPDATE statements of MySQL. DQL abstracts a subset of common ansi sql, so this is not possible. Try with a subselect or IDENTITY ( you must use the latest version of Doctrine 2.2.2 ) :

```
createQuery('update UaePortailBundle:Note u set u.note = ?3
             where IDNETITY(u.inscription) = ?1 and IDENTITY(u.elementmodule) = ?2 ');
```

Comment: i tried this, but, it don't work, because my doctrine version is 2.0

Comment: if you want use DQL ,you must update your doctrine version to 2.2.2 or you can use NativeQuery :)

Answer (score 1):

after searching and trying to find a solution for that using doctrine dql, i was not able to find it, so i used direct sql query to update the database.

```
     $stmt = $this->getEntityManager()
               ->getConnection()
               ->prepare("update note set note = :note where `etudiant_id` like :etudiant_id and `elementmodule_id` like :elementmodule_id");
                $stmt->bindValue('etudiant_id',$etudiant);
                $stmt->bindValue('elementmodule_id' ,$element );
                $stmt->bindValue('note', $note);
                $stmt->execute();
```